# Desktop Disappeared

Tags: unity, nautilus

For some reason, the icons that were on my desktop have disappeared. I am unable to left click on the desktop and do anything like I used to. Any ideas of why it is all of a sudden hiding my desktop icons and folders? And how I can have the show back up, and to activate my left click on the desktop.

Comment: Did you switch to another workspace? Try 'Alt+F2' and log in, see if the files are still in the ~/Desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the issue you're having is that the file manager that runs your desktop, typically Nautilus, has crashed. I'm not sure why it's doing that repeatedly for you, but I'm sure in one of the next releases, the issue will be resolved. That's usually how things work.

I'm assuming that you are still able to access the Unity Dash and/or applications menu. If you happen to be using Nautilus as the desktop manager (which is the default in Ubuntu Unity), usually just opening your home folder will start Nautilus and it will say to itself "oh hey, I need to fill the desktop with the files in ~/Desktop" and will correct itself.

Like I said, I'm not sure why you're having this issue repeatedly, nor why the application crash dialog isn't coming up, but I'd say keep up to date on software updates and Ubuntu releases, and the problem should be solved eventually.

Comment: I used what you suggested and it is back working correctly now. Thank you for the input!